# Can solidity function have optional parameter?

Tags: solidity, function

`buyCoffee` function has only 2 parameters. But if I call `buyCoffee` function with `tip` parameter in the test script, it does work. I tried to find some references in the ethers.js document but I couldn't. How does it work?

```
//BuyMeACoffee.sol
function buyCoffee(string memory _name, string memory _message) public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0, "can't buy coffee with 0 eth");
    }
```

```js
//test script
async function main() {
  //Made test wallet
  const [owner, tipper, tipper1, tipper2] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

  //Deploy contract
  const BuyMeACoffee = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("BuyMeACoffee");
  const buyMeACoffee = await BuyMeACoffee.deploy();
  await buyMeACoffee.deployed();
  console.log("contract got deployed bro", buyMeACoffee.address);

  //Buy coffee
  const tip = {value: hre.ethers.utils.parseEther("1")};
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipper).buyCoffee("Cathy","You're the best!", tip);
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipper1).buyCoffee("Kath","Good Morning :)", tip);
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipper2).buyCoffee("Navie","How cool", tip);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about Solidity, but how ethersjs abstracts the call to the contract and does some encoding and creates the transaction for you.

Basically, from a js contract instance created with ethersjs, when you are calling a method of the contract, the last argument is the 'options' or 'override' ([check the docs here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract-functionsCall)) values that you want your transaction to include. It has nothing to do with the actual contract function in the blockchain. It's just a way to let ethersjs know how to create the transaction that will be sent to the actual smart contract.

Check the docs: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract-functionsCall

And about optional parameters, Solidity does not support optional parameters as of now. Even though you could write a function that declares parameters that don't have variables names, like this:

```js
function updateCounter(uint, uint) {...}
```

You would still need to encode values for each parameter and send them in your transaction.

In JS you can do something like the following to declare a function with an optional parameter `n` that is assigned the value 5 if no value is passed:

```js
function myFunction(n = 5) {...}
```

We don't have something like that in Solidity.